# Chrome text blur with overflow-y:scroll and fixed height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a custom dropdown with some text options, and I need to set a fixed height. Seems simple enough, I added `max-height` and `overflow-y: scroll`. It works great! but on Chrome on device mode, with big resolutions it blurs the text.

I made a pen that shows this.  https://codepen.io/a40637francisco/pen/OvbNyB

It seems these 2 properties don't go well with chrome.

```css
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

I've tried several *fixes* using translate, perspective, smoothing, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks good when I view it in device mode in Chrome (v.65, 64-bit, on Mac). I tried 1024px width and 1280px width. It is blurry, however, when the zoom is anything except 100%. I noticed that Chrome changed my zoom when I'd change the device width. Can you confirm that your zoom is 100%?

Comment: @BSK yes, even with the zoom at 100%, it's still blurry, for example with 600 x 960. (Chrome, Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit) in windows)

Comment: If it looks good on actual devices, I would consider it a bug in Chrome and submit an issue for it.  It is just a generic emulator after all and your QA would be done using real devices or through something reliable like BrowserStack.

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 5):

I guess it has to do with the mobile screen resizing. Setting it to 100% fixed it for me. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 4):

Especially for me helped removing border-radius

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't believe that this helped! thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, it only does this for me with a percentage border radius. If I use a length value like `15px` instead of `2%`, the blurriness disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using also height

```css
height: 100%
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```